# Object floating on heavy sea - how to make shocking rotation less sensitive?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, subdivision-surface, ocean-simulation

So I have an object floating on a heavy sea. How to make it a bit less sensitive to sudden rotation and location changes, and make it look more fluid instead?

I used the technique such as described in  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvKQrXMypsM which uses object contraints (copy location and copy rotation) on a plane that has been srinkwrapped to the fluid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I am solving this now is, unfortunately, by baking the action of the floating object (take a smaller baking step interval) and then smoothing the transitions with bezier curve transitions.